# Whitelisting google fonts apis on my firewall

Tags: firewall, google, css

I've got a machine behind a firewall (fortigate) that is only supposed to access a certain url, so, we whitelisted that url on the firewall and also the google dns servers: Every other traffic is forbidden.
The problem is that said page has some css styles that call the google api for fonts:
fonts.gstatic.com and fonts.googleapis.com (as far as I can tell)

For the life of me, I always get timed out on the fonts when accessing the web page, even though I added the FQDN as permitted traffic.

Am I missing any other url or anything you could come up with? I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe you're missing two another:

- www.googleapis.com (auth for the API);
- themes.googleusercontent.com (URL of each font).

Also, if the app uses the Webfont Loader, is also good to give access to the host:

- ajax.googleapis.com.

Got it here:

- https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api
- https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader

Best luck!